# Laravel redirect admin to admin/

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Problem: redirect from admin to admin/ in Laravel 5.

Here is my .htaccess of public (root folder for domain):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

`admin` url is managed by admin IndexController.
Important thing, wthich makes the problem, is that I have admin folder in public folder. So when I type `admin` it redirects to `admin/`. Though `admin/smth` does not redirect and everything is ok.

The problems disappears when I remove admin folder from public. But I want to leave it. Is it possible or should I rename admin folder?

Answer (score 2):

The Best option here is to remove or rename the admin folder from the public folder because by default laravel will access to this folder at it was the root folder.